# Why does dividing with arrays generate random number?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

So, here's my code

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int kw[10];
    int discount[10];
    int total[10];
    int final[10];

    cout << "insert amount of data = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "insert total = ";
        cin >> total[i];
        cout << "insert kw (1, 2, or 3)= ";
        cin >> kw[i];

        if (kw[i] < 1 || kw[i] > 3) {
            do {
                cout << "please insert the number 1-3\n";
                cout << "insert kw (1, 2, or 3)= ";
                cin >> kw[i];
            } while (kw[i] < 1 || kw[i] > 3);

            if (kw[i] == 1) {
                discount[i] = 2 * total[i] / 100;
            }

            else if (kw[i] == 2) {
                discount[i] = 5 * total[i] / 100;
            }

            else
                discount[i] = 10 * total[i] / 100;
        }
        final[i] = total[i] - discount[i];
        cout << discount[i] << endl;
        cout << final[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to take how many times the user will run the program, take the number the user inputted, set the discount, then calculate the final value.

The problem is, the end result is always a random number. For example, if I input `5000` for the `total[i]` and `3` for the `kw[i]` (`kw[i]` is used to set the discount), I would get the result:

```
6299760                                                                                                      
-6294760
```

While I expected to get:

```
500
4500
```

So, how can I fix this so that I can get the correct value?

Comment: Your code can easily go havok with right/wrong input, please include all input and output.

Comment: You aren't setting discount if they get kw right on the first try.

Comment: Building on @stark's comment, if you find yourself writing `if(condition){ do{ ...} while(condition) }`, you probably just want a `while` loop instead of a `do while` loop.

Comment: Also, search your favorite C++ reference for "integer division".  Your `discount` calculations will be zero if the numerator is less than the denomenator, e.g. 3/4 == 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate `discount` only if the user first enters wrong value for `kw`, and then enters the right one.